# Android start new activity

Tags: android

I have created a list in xml,android.And its java code has extend Activity and not extend List activity.I m not able to write a code to start new activity wen i click a particular row.here is my code...

JAVA CODE

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends Activity {
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,``
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            ListView View = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            View.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"> 

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what kind of activity do you want to start when clicking on a particular item?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Do you need help with responding to the user clicking on an item in the list? Or do you need help with starting another activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,``
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            ListView View = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            View.setAdapter(adapter);
            view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You chose item number: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `setOnItemClickListener` on the `list` and check the `position` and start the appropriate `Intent`. Something like this...

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Check which list item was clicked by checking the 'position' 
        // and start an Activity accordingly
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent oneIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OneFragment.class);
            startActivity(oneIntent);
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent twoIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TwoFragment.class);
            startActivity(twoIntent);
        // AND SO ON...
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        switch(position) {
        case 0:

            Intent intnscnd = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondactivity.class);
            startActivity(intnscnd);
            this.finish();
            break;
        case 1:

            Intent intnthrd = new Intent(MainActivity.this, thirdactivity.class);
            startActivity(intnthrd);
            this.finish();

        }
    }
});
```